# Cleaning \u2764\ufe0f \u2026 data in file with python

Tags: python, regex, sentiment-analysis, preprocessor, data-cleaning

I try to cleaning data twitter in python with regex, but i can't remove `\u2764\ufe0f \u2026`. twitter data is in the datas.txt file, this is the data:

> Berkat biznet aku bisa online terimakasih BiznetHome \u2764\ufe0f
>   Gangguan hari sabtu perbaikan nanti senin  hari offline Slow respon \u2764\ufe0f Terima kasih TelkomCare masalah indihome sy sudah terselesaikan terima kasih fast responnya terus selalu tingka\u2026 TelkomCare Sudah beres fix internet dan telpon berfungsi normal thanks atas respons dan perbaikan pihak Indihom\u2026

I have tried three ways :

First

```py
import re

with open ('datas.txt', 'r') as f:
     mylist = [line for line in f]
emoji_pattern = re.compile(r'\\\\u\w+')
for i in mylist:
    print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', i))
```

Second

```py
import re
f = open('datas.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
                u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
                u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
                u'\U00010000-\U0010ffff'
                u"\u200d"
                u"\u2640-\u2642"
                u"\u2600-\u2B55"
                u"\u23cf"
                u"\u23e9"
                u"\u231a"
                u"\u3030"
                u"\ufe0f"
    "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
emoji_pattern.sub(r'', data)
```

third

```py
f= open("datas.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8")
datas = f.read()
data = datas.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode("utf-8")
print(data)
```

but still not work

Comment: I tried the regex in you example text and `\u2764\ufe0f` seem to be removed. `\u2026`, which an [horizontal ellipsis](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2026), is not removed, but it is not covered by your regex either. The third approach seems to remove all non-ascii characters.

Comment: have you tried taking data in the "datas.txt" file?

Comment: Ah wait, you mean the content of your `datas.txt` file is that, as we are seeing there? I mean when you write `\u2764` in your example you don't mean "the Unicode code point 0x2764" but rather "backslash, u, two, seven, six, four", then? And if that is the case, does it include the quotation marks at the beginning and end too?

Comment: if you try with 
```python
s = 'Berkat biznet aku bisa online terimakasih BiznetHome \u2764\ufe0f \u2026'
print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', s))
```
working, but if you take the data from the file "datas.txt" thats still not work

Comment: Right so in that case `\u2764\ufe0f` are removed for me (with the `emoji_pattern` from your second snippet) but the `\u2026` remains there, as it is not within the code points in the regex.

Comment: wait @jdehesa i'll show my data

Comment: if the case is like this `python s = 'Berkat biznet aku bisa online terimakasih BiznetHome \u2764\ufe0f \u2026' print(emoji_pattern.sub(r'', s))` it can be deleted. But if you retrieve the data from "datas.txt" `\u2764\ufe0f \u2026` it cannot be removed

Comment: @jdehesa this the data http://www.imagebam.com/image/6266fa1174399504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file contains non-ASCII Unicode codepoints encoded according to [how Python encodes Unicode literals in source code](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code). There are two things you can do with that:

- Delete all `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX` sequences from your data. This will remove all Unicode codepoints written in Python literal format, which, in principle (although not necessarily), will be non-ASCII characters. That can be done for example like this:

```py
import re

with open ('datas.txt', 'r') as f:
     mylist = [line for line in f]
unicode_literal = re.compile(r'\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}')
for i in mylist:
    print(unicode_literal.sub(r'', i))
```

- Interpret Unicode code points as their intended value. That is, you will get a string with the non-ASCII data corresponding to the codepoints expressed in the text file. You can do that like this:

```py
# Note file is read in byte mode
with open ('datas.txt', 'rb') as f:
     mylist = [line for line in f]
for i in mylist:
    print(mylist.decode('unicode-escape'))
```