# How to convert junk values of a specific column (column type: object) to NaN values in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Link to my data frame output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xKNQ.jpg)

I want to convert missing values of the column ["Energy Supply"] coded as "..." according to the output and the excel file to NaN values. Whenever I does this, it shows no error but it does not show when I run it again, it's still ".........". Here are the things I tried:

```
df["Energy Supply"]=df["Energy Supply"].astype('str')
df["Energy Supply"].replace({"...":str(np.NaN)}, inplace=True)
```

and

```
df["Energy Supply"]=df["Energy Supply"].astype('str')
df["Energy Supply"].replace({".................................................":np.NaN}, inplace=True)
```

But when I convert 321000000 to NaN, it appears in the data frame output correctly:

```
df["Energy Supply"]=df["Energy Supply"].astype('str')
df["Energy Supply"].replace({"321000000":np.NaN}, inplace=True)
```

What seems to be the issue? Kindly help.

Comment: Did you try using a regular expression approach instead of string literals?

Comment: @jsb It gives an error if I use .replace() without the string literals. For eg,    
    #df["Energy Supply"]=df["Energy Supply"].astype('str')   \\\\  df["Energy Supply"].replace({..:np.NaN}, inplace=True). Kindly let me know if this wasn't what you meant.

Comment: Why do you wrap `np.NaN` with the `str()` function? If you want a string literal "NaN", just use that.

Comment: @jsb I also used `np.NaN` without `str()`. It didn't work.

Comment: Did you open up the Excel file in e.g. NotePad++ to see if there are other invisible characters in the cells with dots? It could be a special ellipsis character code 0133, in Unicode U+2026.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a repeated ellipsis character. Try using regex instead of string literal and u"\u2026" for the Unicode character "horizontal ellipsis" (U+2026). Also, perhaps this Stack Overflow post is helpful: [Cleaning \u2764\ufe0f \u2026 data in file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342594/cleaning-u2764-ufe0f-u2026-data-in-file-with-python)